# Exporting middleware globally to all routes

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, middleware

So I have been working with PassportJS in adding authentication to my site. I am interested in selectively displaying content that reflects whether or not a user is logged in or if he/she is an owner of a document.

I have the following files

**app.js (entry point)**

```
//Express set up
let express = require("express");
app = express();
serverPort = 8000;
io = require('socket.io')();

//BodyParser set up
bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


//Mongoose set up
mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/Woof");

//Models settings
Dog = require("./models/dog");
User = require("./models/user");

//Seed file set up and run!
seed = require("./models/seed");
seed();

//Routes
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(require('./routes/dogOwners'));
app.use(require('./routes/landing'));
app.use(require('./routes/loginAndRegister'));
app.use(require('./routes/map'));
app.use(require('./routes/dog'));

//req.user avalaible to all routes
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  next();
});

//App settings
app.set('port', serverPort);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('sockets', []);

//Servloger listen:
let server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**loginAndRegistration.js** These are the authentication routes

```
let express = require('express');
router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
User = require("../models/user")

//AUTHENTICATION
let passport = require("passport");
LocalStratergy = require("passport-local");

//PASSPORT CONFIGURATION
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "I wanna go poopie",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  next();
});
passport.use(new LocalStratergy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

router.get('/login', function(req,res){
    res.render('login');
});

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: "/main",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
}), function(req, res) {
});

router.get('/logout', function(req,res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/");
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    res.render('register', {});
});


router.post("/register", function(req, res) {
    User.register(new User({ username: req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(error, newlyCreatedUser) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("COULD NOT REGISTER USER IN THE POST ROUTE");
            res.render("register");
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
                let user = req.body.user;
                newlyCreatedUser.name = user.name;
                newlyCreatedUser.nickname = user.nickname;
                newlyCreatedUser.address = user.address;
                newlyCreatedUser.email = user.email;
                newlyCreatedUser.numberOfDogs = user.numberOfDogs;
                newlyCreatedUser.url = "/user/" + newlyCreatedUser.id;
                newlyCreatedUser.save(function(error, savedUser) {
                    console.log("USER REGISTERED");
                    res.render('maps', {
                        gmapsCredential: credentials.gmaps,
                        'authorized': true
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
});

function isLoggedIn (req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect("/login");
}

module.exports = router;
```

I wanna be able to call `isLoggedIn` in all my routes, but I can only use it in the auth routes. How do I selectively export that function alone to all my routes? I also wanna be able to refer to the varaible `currentUser` in all my `.ejs` files, however it only works in `.ejs` files associated with the auth routes. How do I check for currentUser in all my `.ejs` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crux of your problems are you’ve got too much buried in your `loginAndRegistration.js` file.

First and foremost, if you want to run `isLoggedIn` for every route you need to make sure Passport is configured first i.e.

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  next();
});
passport.use(new LocalStratergy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

Needs to be setup *before* you configure any auth middleware. This will also solve your `.ejs` problem as `user` will now be getting serialised for every route and not just the auth ones.

Finally, you can configure your middleware before any routes you want to enforce authentication on

```
app.use(isLoggedIn);
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants all routes to require a login, just some, but wants to be able to determine from all routes if the user is logged in.

Comment: @jfriend00 maybe so, I based my answer off what the asked. It’s as simple as moving the middleware in that case (I edited to explain)